# How to generate and ordered, subsetted dataframe that is X elements long or less

Tags: r, subset

I have a large data frame (df). I would like to produce df2 from here. df2 must fill these criteria:

1) Sub setted by value in one of the columns.

2) df2 must have a length of 20 elements or less.

3) df2 must be ordered by increasing value

My attempts:

```
A <- floor(runif(100, min = 1, max = 100))
B <- floor(runif(100, min = 1, max = 100))
as.data.frame(cbind(A, B)) -> df

head(df[which(df$A < 50),], n = 20) -> df2
```

This works okay but I'd like the output to be 20 elements long or less.

```
head(df[which(df$A < 50),], n < 20) -> df2
```

```
<=/=</<
```

All result in 'n' not being found.

```
order(head(df[which(df$A < 20),], decreasing = False)) -> df2
```

Kind of works but produces a list rather than a data frame. Also when I try my output is not increasing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how did you select 50 in `df$A < 50` ? is it any arbitrary number? and it should be ordered by which column ?

Comment: Yes, it is an arbitrary number. Just as an example. It could be ordered by either, let's say column A for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was trying to do it in one-liner in base R but it was becoming really ugly so here is a two step solution

```
temp <- df[head(which(df$A < 50), 20), ]
temp[order(temp$A), ]

#    A  B
#4   4 24
#35  7 49
#13  9 16
#39 10 44
#1  12 41
#26 14  8
#14 15 11
#11 16 92
#31 17 17
#20 19 95
#2  20 78
#6  30 94
#16 33 66
#12 34 70
#25 35 21
#9  41 69
#15 41 28
#18 43 37
#5  48 58
#22 49 24
```

---

However, with `dplyr` you can do it in one chain operation

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(A < 50) %>%
  slice(1:20) %>%
  arrange(A)
```

You can change the value 50 and 20 based on your preference.

**data**

```
set.seed(2345)
A <- floor(runif(100, min = 1, max = 100))
B <- floor(runif(100, min = 1, max = 100))
as.data.frame(cbind(A, B)) -> df
```